# How to show/hide Keyboard on Ubuntu Tablet

Tags: keyboard, tablet

In Ubuntu Tablet, V15.05 OTA-10.1, the Keyboard is not visible in e.g. Firefox, LibreOffice.
How can I Pop up the Keyboard on Ubuntu Tablet
Thanks for any help

Comment: On my BQ Aquaris 10 FHD with OTA-10.1 it appears any time you tap on a text input field (such as the body of a LibreOffice document, web form or URL bar.)  I haven't found a way to force it to appear otherwise.  However, if you have a BT keyboard currently paired, it doesn't appear.

Comment: Thanks Tony. You're right for most of the apps. But for the two mentioned it doesn't work. And no, I don't use a BT keyboard currently. So, I need to find another method. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

It says in the manual (p47) in the footer that "some apps such as GIMP, LibreOffice and Xchat-Gnome are deigned to be used in convergent mode only". In other words they will require an external keyboard and/or mouse.
https://it-bqcom15-media.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/resources/manual/Aquaris_M10_Ubuntu_Edition_Complete_User_Manual-1460548936.pdf

---

I don't think the mentioned apps (Firefox and LibreOffice currently support the touch keyboard. I can't find any solid links to back it up, but I have not seen any record in the web showing it working. This guy also thinks they shipped some apps only to be used with an external keyboard: http://blog.afandian.com/2016/04/i-got-a-bq-aquaris-m10-ubuntu-tablet/

gedit is another one that could do with keyboard touch access.

I think they are legasy apps that run in a container and don't access to the touch keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, you're probably right. I didn't think on that